# MS Access: Code order gets mixed up after sorting to another table

Tags: ms-access-2007

I've been struggling with this for quite some hours now.

I've got a query, that exports certain fields from a table to another table:

SELECT ALLQuotes.Ddate, ALLQuotes.Ttime, ALLQuotes.Price INTO 27012016_29012016
FROM ALLQuotes
ORDER BY ALLQuotes.Code;

The problem is, for some rows it mixes up and codes do not come ordered, like they are in the initial table. Here's a screenshot:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edDrt.jpg)

And here how it looks in the original table:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Scy4.jpg)

Could this be perhaps caused by the large ammount of raws that i have? (around 4.2 million)?

And how can I export sorted data so that I don't counter this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If you first create your `27012016_29012016` table with an autonumber ID field in addition to the Ddate, Ttime, and Price fields and then use an "append query" to load `ALLQuotes` data into it, do you get the record order you expect?  `INSERT INTO [27012016_29012016] (Ddate, Ttime, Price) SELECT aq.Ddate, aq.Ttime, aq.Price FROM ALLQuotes AS aq ORDER BY aq.Code;`

Comment: Yeah that works and i get the same order. Thanks! However, now I notice that the initial table also has a messed up order. How can i combine the above query with sorting the code initial table?